# AFNetworking base64 parameter, characters being escaped by NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, json, base64, afnetworking, nsjsonserialization

I am attempting to submit an image to [CardShark's API](http://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/cardshark/) using AFNetworking.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(cardImage, 1.0);
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"front" : [imageData base64EncodedStringWithSeparateLines:NO]};

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cardShark?webhookUrl=%@&apiKey=%@", kCardSharkWebHookURLEncodedString, kCardSharkAPIKey];

[self postPath:path parameters:parameters
       success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    completion(responseObject, nil);
}
       failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    completion(nil, error);
}];
```

I've tried all combinations of the base64 string.

```
base64EncodedStringWithSeparateLines:YES
base64EncodedStringWithSeparateLines:NO
base64EncodedString`
```

To no avail, after inspecting the `HTTPBody` on the request that is generated I am seeing that things are being escaped.

The raw base64 starts with

`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAAB
AAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAEOKAD
AAQAAAABAAACrAAAAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB`

But once it's gone through AFNetworking and presumably NSJSONSerialization it is being posted as

`\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAEOKADAAQAAAABAAACrAAAAAD\/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH\/`

As you can see the `/` are being escaped. How do I prevent the escaping? Passing the exact JSON body to the API via another tool (a la, curl) causes the API to produce an error. So what's the best approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was more of the fault of the API. AFNetworking has the following code that sets the Content-Type header with `charset=utf-8`.

```
case AFJSONParameterEncoding:;
                    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json; charset=%@", charset] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                    [request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:&error]];
                    break;
```

For whatever reason that is beyond my understanding, their API did not support the `charset` attribute on the header.

With that said, they were fast to fix this issue and it is now working with no modification to the code shown above.

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue with RestKit , can you please help me out what code modification and in which file they need to be done ? RestKit still uses AFN 1.3 so i guess I need to modify code, you can answer my question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318016/prevent-restkit-from-adding-escape-characters